# Agregar Tab con contenido personalizado a la zona de administración de WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Buen día
Me encontré con un problema nuevo para mi, deseo agregar un tab personalizado (así como hacen algunos pluggin) a mi zona de administración, que al dar clic muestre el diseño HTML que cree, lo siento por no adjuntar código el problema es nuevo para mi no sé por dónde tomarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar un panel al dashboard primero hay que agregar un elemento al menú enganchandose al action [`'admin_menu'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu) que puede tomar una función o como en este ejemplo una custom class, luego dentro de esa función agregas el panel en sí con [`add_dashboard_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_dashboard_page).

Es en esta última función donde se definen los parámetros:

- título de la página
- título del item de menú
- capabilities mínimas que debe tener el usuario para poder ver el panel
- el slug del panel que debe ser único
- la función encargada de renderizar el contenido del panel

La forma de imprimir el custom HTML es variada, hay varios ejemplos en el code, la mas simple es inline.

---

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
// evitar el acceso directo

define('CHILD_THEME_DIR', get_stylesheet_directory());
// definimos una constante para cargar archivos desde
// la carpeta del child theme

$object = new soes302146customAdminPanel();

// Hook para agregar admin menus
// https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu
add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $object, 'addMenu' ] );

class soes302146customAdminPanel{
  // definimos una clase para agrupar todo lo de este panel

  /**
  * Crear un item de menú en el dashboard
  * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_dashboard_page
  */
  public function addMenu(){
    add_dashboard_page(
      'Panel con custom HTML', // título de la página
      'ver el custom HTML', // título del menú
      'manage_options', // capabilities requeridas para poder ver la tab:
      // https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/
      // 'manage_options' solo visible para administradores
      // 'read' es visible para todos los usuarios
      'soes302146-custom-html-viewer', // slug del menu, debe ser único
      // la url final quedará algo así:
      // www.midominio.com/wp-admin/index.php?page=soes302146-custom-html-viewer
      [ $this, 'dashboardPage' ] // función que imprime el contenido
    );
  }

  /**
  * Aquí es donde se imprime el contenido
  * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_dashboard_page
  */
  public function dashboardPage(){
    ob_start();
    // empezamos la captura del output buffer
    ?>
    <style>
      /* CSS inline */
      h1 { color:#f00;}
    </style>
    <h1>html inline</h1>
    <script>
      /* javascript inline */
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        // código
        alert('hola!');
      });
    </script>
    <?php
    /* variantes para renderizar el contenido */
    /* CSS inline desde archivo */
    /*
    echo '<style>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo file_get_contents( CHILD_THEME_DIR . '/templates/custom-html.css' );
    echo '</style>' . PHP_EOL;
    //*/

    /* html inline desde php ( templates/custom-html.php ) */
    /*
    get_template_part( 'templates/custom-html' );
    //*/

    /* html inline desde html ( templates/custom-html.html ) */
    /*
    echo file_get_contents( CHILD_THEME_DIR . '/templates/custom-html.html' );
    //*/

    /* Javascript inline desde archivo */
    /*
    echo '<script>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo file_get_contents( CHILD_THEME_DIR . '/templates/custom-html.js' );
    echo '</script>' . PHP_EOL;
    //*/
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    // se recupera el buffer y se imprime
    echo $output;
  }
}
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!